# How to nest low level errors and higher level errors?

Tags: swift

I have a custom error type, for low level HTTP problems:

```
enum APIClientError: ErrorType {
    case NetworkError
    ...
}
```

In a higher level layer I have another error type:

```
enum SignInError: ErrorType {
    case InvalidUser
    ...
}
```

The problem I have is that those `APIClientError` instances need to bubble up to the higher level layer and in my function I need to return maybe an `APIClientError`, maybe an `SignInError`.

How can I declare a function like that? I tried

```
typealias LoginResult = Result<SuccessType, ErrorType>
```

But I does not work ('Using ErrorType' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'ErrorType' is not supported').

How can I nest error types from different layers in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

I am also scratching my head about this.  The only way I can think of doing it is like this:

```
 enum APIClientError: ErrorType {
   case NetworkError
   ...
 }


 enum SignInError: ErrorType {
   case InvalidUser
   //note, the name of the case can't be the same as the type of the error due to compiler errors
   case APIError(APIClientError)
 }
```

This way errors will bubble up.  The only annoying thing about this would be unwrapping multiple levels of error nesting by the code that handles the errors.